# Can't send mail from WordPress after configuring sSMTP

Tags: server, email, wordpress, ssmtp, cms

This is my `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` with omitted root, email, password, and hostname:

```
root=my_gmail_email@gmail.com
AuthUser=my_gmail_email@gmail.com
AuthPass=my_gmail_password
hostname=my_host_name

mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

The file permissions are `rw-r-----`.

---

Although I had this conf saved I still got an error in WordPress (by the C[ontact Form 7 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), or CF7 in short).

No `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/ssmtp.log` or any log file with a similar name was created (and I know I can create these with `touch` and assumed I'll do so if I'll feel it's really needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I understood what was the problem, I took care of it, and then the email was sent successfully.

### Preface

To understand my answer below, one has to ensure understanding of how email data gets transferred from a CMS (WordPress in this case), all the way to the final, destined email account. This chain describe it:

> [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) and its contact form (WordPress with CF7) → php's `mail()` function → `sSMTP` → [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) (web
>   service) → email-proxy station (Gmail) → final email destination
>   (Gmail);

### The problem and its solution

My `sSMTP` conf above was actually just fine. The problem came from my email proxy to which I've sent the data via `sSMTP` (Gmail):

You see, after you create an email account which will serve as a proxy (a medium) between the content sent via SMTP to your final destined email address, this proxy is generally useless for `sSMTP` and similar tools until you enable something in that email proxy itself !

In my email proxy, Gmail, what I had to enable is called **"access for less secure apps"**.

1. I got an email to Gmail saying **"Review blocked sign-in attempt"**. I opened the email, and understood that Gmail will approve the IP address from which this data came if if I allow it. This email address is my VPS machine's IP.
2. I allowed getting email sent via `sSMTP` which Google deemed "less secure app". I then I tried to send an email again from WordPress. This time, it went fine.

### Summary

The problem was on Gmail's side --- I had to enable "access for less secure apps" there, then the email was sent and the data reached its final destination.

---

### Notes

1. That's a bit off topic but when I first started to learn on `sSMTP` I asked myself "how to ensure sSMTP` will work with more than one application. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016850/cant-send-mail-from-wordpress-after-configuring-ssmtp) I got the answer at the time.